# How to make a Thunderbird attachment readable to snap apps such as LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, snap, thunderbird

Since LibreOffice became a snap package it can not find an attachment to a mail in Thunderbird when this is clicked to open. Of course there is the work-around to download the attachment explicitly, but this is bad because it requires you to explicitly remove the file created if you don't want to keep it. This seems according to a number of answers a design feature. How can I change this behavior?
In my opinion, does this behavior violate the "Unix design ideas"?

Comment: So why do you use the snap and don't install the deb-package then. It's available in official reposiories or directly from [libroffice.org](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/download-libreoffice/).

Comment: @mook765 libreoffice as deb, at least on 20.04, is absolutely non-trivial: it involves a bunch of packages and upgrading to a more recent version is so challenging that I could not bring myself to even attempting it yet. That's why I read with excitement that there is a snap variant, from which I expect that I will be able to enjoy more recent releases without much hassle. I would therefore vote to put effort into ironing out any inconveniences that accompany the snap variant: achieving similar degree of integration as with the deb, but leaving behind the suboptimailities, would be nice.

Comment: There are also [appimages](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/appimage/) you could try and see if they work better for you.

Comment: The problem applies not only to libreoffice ... I am aware of the work-around to use non-snap versions of apps, but this is a WORK-AROUND and not a solution.